# Magento continue shopping url custom change

Tags: php, magento-2.0

I'm totally new to Magento(not even 2 weeks of experience)
My problem is to change continue shopping button in a way that it would go back to last category from which we bought item recently. I found a solution in Magento 1.7 but I m using 2.1 version in which some classes are missing or are different. Could someone advise me how it should look like ? For now Im using contineShoppingUrl with method GetBaseUrl and static link added to it, but I'd like it to work dynamically.

```
 public function getContinueShoppingUrl()
    {
        return $this->getBaseUrl();
    }
```

Whatsmore I'd like it work from code level not configuration.

Regards,

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/84980/how-to-get-magento2-base-url maybe?

Comment: It is not exacly what I need. I already have base URL but i want to add last category URL to the base URL. For example I buy a mouse from category Devices. And I have also categories like Books and Software. After clicking ContinueShopping I d like to get url back to category Devices. I was thinking about some Javascript here but I aint sure if it is good idea.

Comment: Since Magento is so heavily reliant on JS anyway, a little more is unlikely to hurt - however, there is this on the Magento SE : https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/94977/how-to-redirect-to-previous-page-magento-2